# Is there any option for printing the graphs generated by c3js?

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, c3.js

```js
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        // iris data from R
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30],
            ['data2', 120],
        ],
        type: 'pie',
        onclick: function (d, i) { console.log("onclick", d, i); },
        onmouseover: function (d, i) { console.log("onmouseover", d, i); },
        onmouseout: function (d, i) { console.log("onmouseout", d, i); }
    }
});

setTimeout(function () {
    chart.load({
        columns: [
            ["setosa", 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.6, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2],
            ["versicolor", 1.4, 1.5, 1.5, 1.3, 1.5, 1.3, 1.6, 1.0, 1.3, 1.4, 1.0, 1.5, 1.0, 1.4, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.0, 1.5, 1.1, 1.8, 1.3, 1.5, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.4, 1.7, 1.5, 1.0, 1.1, 1.0, 1.2, 1.6, 1.5, 1.6, 1.5, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.2, 1.4, 1.2, 1.0, 1.3, 1.2, 1.3, 1.3, 1.1, 1.3],
            ["virginica", 2.5, 1.9, 2.1, 1.8, 2.2, 2.1, 1.7, 1.8, 1.8, 2.5, 2.0, 1.9, 2.1, 2.0, 2.4, 2.3, 1.8, 2.2, 2.3, 1.5, 2.3, 2.0, 2.0, 1.8, 2.1, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 2.1, 1.6, 1.9, 2.0, 2.2, 1.5, 1.4, 2.3, 2.4, 1.8, 1.8, 2.1, 2.4, 2.3, 1.9, 2.3, 2.5, 2.3, 1.9, 2.0, 2.3, 1.8],
        ]
    });
}, 1500);

setTimeout(function () {
    chart.unload({
        ids: 'data1'
    });
    chart.unload({
        ids: 'data2'
    });
}, 2500);
```

How to add the option to print the graphs in c3js? Or is there any way to convert this c3js to canvas from its svg representation.

Comment: Using Javascript, why can't you just print the SVG as is? See an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21660843/print-only-svg-from-browser)

Comment: Updated with a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/serendipity/wLow6wsj/) to demonstrate printing. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just print the content of the chart div like this

```
<div id="chart">
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="printDiv('chart')" value="print a div!" />

function printDiv(divName) {
     var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
     var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

     document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

     window.print();

     document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
```

link:[How to print HTML content on click of a button, but not the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16894683/how-to-print-html-content-on-click-of-a-button-but-not-the-page)

Comment: Replacing the entire document body can damage dinamic content; I'd recommend using an `<iframe>` to do the printing, so as to not mess up with the main page..

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. Very simple css :)

```
@media print{
  .c3 path, .c3 line {    
    fill: none; 
    stroke: #000;
}
```