# Open inline SVG in new window - Javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a `<div>` that contains an inline `svg`. I would like a function that opens that `svg` in a new tab/window. I only want to use the front-end js without having to save the `svg` anywhere.

If I use `window.open()`, it puts the svg inside an `<html>` tag which I'm trying to avoid.

I'm basically trying to change this answer but then only have the svg code left:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21667339/1083923

```
//---print button---
    var printSVG = function()
    {
        var popUpAndPrint = function()
        {
            var container = $('#svgDiv');
            var width = parseFloat(container.getAttribute("width"))
            var height = parseFloat(container.getAttribute("height"))
            var printWindow = window.open('', 'PrintMap',
            'width=' + width + ',height=' + height);
            printWindow.document.writeln($(container).html());
            printWindow.document.close();
            printWindow.print();
            printWindow.close();
        };
        setTimeout(popUpAndPrint, 500);
    };
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can stringify your element into a valid SVG document and store it as a Blob, then point your new Window to that Blob using a blob:// URI:

```
// we need to handle a user gesture to use 'open'
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = (evt) => {
  // grab your svg element
  const svg = document.querySelector("svg");
  // convert to a valid XML source
  const as_text = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg);
  // store in a Blob
  const blob = new Blob([as_text], { type: "image/svg+xml" });
  // create an URI pointing to that blob
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const win = open(url);
  // so the Garbage Collector can collect the blob
  win.onload = (evt) => URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
};
```

[JS-fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/L5sab921/) since StackSnippet's sand-boxed iframes don't allow opening new windows.